# Rails and JavaScript. Wrong length on unix timestamps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, unix-timestamp

I am developing an application in Javascript using Appcelerator and I need to compare
two different UNIX timestamps.

The problem is one gets longer then the other which makes it bigger even though it is not.

The long one is generated via javascript like this:

```
var d = new Date();

value.httpCacheCreated = d.getTime();
```

And the result is:

```
1309443190619
```

And its human readable value is:

```
Thu, 30 Jun 2011 14:13:10 gmt
```

The short one is generated from Rails like this:

```
current_user.updated_at.to_time.to_i
```

And the result is:

```
1309442086
```

And its human readable value is:

```
Thu, 30 Jun 2011 13:54:46 gmt
```

When you look at the human readable the short one is newer but if I compare them, the long one being longer and the comparison fails.

So how can I get the to be the same size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

javascript getTime() gives you number of milliseconds while Ruby's Time#to_i gives you number of seconds

just get rid of last 3 digit's in javascript's version and you will have ruby's version

Comment: it doesn't work:
``new Date(Number(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))).toISOString()``
JS unix time has length of 13, and ruby has the length of 10, but converting it to 10 resets the time back to 1970